# Can you have a vector of arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to keep a vector of numbers. I'm not sure what having a vector of arrays looks like, but I'd imagine it looks like this:

```
std::vector<int[5]> myvector;
```

And then access it like this:

```
myvector[3][4] = 3;
```

Strangely (or not) I've never seen this technique before. Is there a reason for it. Is it just inherently uncommon for such a thing? Or would it be better to wrap the array in a class object type?

Comment: C-style arrays aren’t cooiable, so they can’t be the element type in a vector. `std::array`, on the other hand …

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<int,5>> myvector;`

Answer (score 7):

In general you can not create a vector of arrays because arrays do not have the assignment operator and the copy constructor.

But you can create a vector of objects of the type `std::array<int, 5>`

Comment: Formally, the type needs to be [*Erasable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Erasable)

Comment: but many member functions impose stricter requirement https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#:~:text=requirements%20of%20Erasable%2C-,but%20many%20member%20functions%20impose%20stricter%20requirements.,-This%20container%20(but